# Find $\iint_{U} \frac{x}{y+x^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

Could you help me with the following please:
Evaluate

$$\iint_{U} \frac{x}{y+x^{2}}dxdy$$

where $U$ is limited by $x = 1$, $y=x^{2}$, $y=4-x^{2}$. Suggestion consider $x=\sqrt{v-u}$ and find $y$ as a function of $u$ and $v$ and apply change of variable.

I have plotted the region and searched how to find $y$, to obtain the transformation and to be able to calculate the Jacobian, if you could please help me find it $y$ or if you could give me some advice, thank you.

Comment: That suggestion is useless. I can choose any $y(u,v)$ and all that would change are the limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt 2}dx \int_{x^2}^{4-x^2}\frac{x}{y+x^{2}}dy$$
imho is more easy direct integrating.